# Express the statement using predicates and quantifiers.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Ex: A passenger on an airline qualifies as a frequent flier if the passenger flies more than $25,000$ miles in one year or takes more than $25$ flights during that year.

I started and made up these three propositions knowing $x$ is a passenger:

$P(x)$ = passenger qualifies as a frequent flier

$R(x)$ = passenger flies more than $25,000$ miles in one year

$S(x)$ = passenger takes more than $25$ flights during that year

Not sure how to symbolize $P(x)\; IF\; (R(x)\; OR\; S(x))$

Comment: You need to define sets, then you can define functions which map from that set to true or false.  Should look something like: $\forall x \in \mathbb{P}: P(x) \rightarrow (R(x)\wedge S(x))$.

Comment: @Jared To be fair, here the predicate would be $(R(x)\wedge S(x))\to P(x)$, because the antecedent is the part that comes after the "if".

Comment: @G.Sassatelli If the meaning is that if $R(x) \wedge S(x)$ then $x$ is definitely a frequent flier but if they _don't_ meet those requirements it's still possible they are frequent flyers, then yes that would be correct.  Also, the way I and the OP put it, it's possible that the passenger _does_ meet those requirements but is _not_ a frequent flyer.

Comment: @Jared The fact is that, as far as I know, the correct way to interpret "$A$ if $B$" in English is "if $B$ then $A$" (meaning that if $B$ is true, then $A$ is true), or "$B\to A$". In mahematical Englis, "$A\to B$" is commonly worded, "$A$ only if $B$", meaning that "if $B$ fails $A$ fails".

Comment: @Jared By the way, the condition was $R(x)\vee S(x)$. And I don't agree with the fact that $R(x)\vee S(x)$ is a necessary, but not sufficient condition. If I read that, I had flied 30000 miles and I were exhonerated because I weight 70kg, I would be extremely upset.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli If it means that the passenger _will_ be a frequent flyer when they meet those requirement and, that if a passenger is a frequent flyer then they meet those requirements, then it's a double implication: $P(x) \leftrightarrow (R(x) \wedge S(x))$.

Comment: That's another thing, I agree. What I say is that the correct way to interpret the text is "$R(x)\vee S(x)$ is a sufficient condition", but not a necessary one, a priori. Nowhere it states that being a Raptor is not a sufficient condition to qualify as a frequent flier, though many people would exclude it a priori.

Answer (score 0):

$P(x)$ IF $R(x) \lor $S(x) is equivalent to IF $R(x) \lor S(x)$ THEN $P(x)$, which translates to $R(x) \lor S(x) \to P(x)$ .
**Edit**: After the edit of the post it seems to now longer be clear how to translate $R(x)$ OR $S(x)$ - this is simply disjunction: $R(x) \lor S(x)$. I see no reason to try and go with a conjuuction or even an exclusive or; to me it seems clear that the *or* in the sentence equates a simple inclusive logical *or*, i.e. $\lor$.
**Edit 2**: After ther was some discussion in the comments about it, you could, as epxlained in my [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1822986/344246), also make the implication a biconditional:
$R(x) \lor S(x) \leftrightarrow P(x)$
This means that a passenger qualifies for a frequent flier *if and only if* $R(x) \lor S(x)$ holds true, and if this is false, no other condition can make $P(x)$ true. This would make $R(x) \lor S(x)$ a *necessary* condition.
I think, however, that in this not the intended meaning, I could imagine that one could posssibly also qualify for a frequent flier if, for example, one has made a certain amount of flights within the course of a longer time range, without having made it within a year but instead, say, 50.000 miles within the course of two and a half years. In that sense, I rather think that $R(x) \lor S(x)$ is a *sufficient* condition, but not a necessary one, as proposed b @G. Sassatelli in the comments, and would therefore be translated with a material implication *if* $\to$ rather than a biconditional *iff* $\to$.
In either case, if $R(x) \lor S(x)$ is true, $P(x)$ must be true. If that is not the case, the implication simply does not hold: If the antecedent is true but the consequent is false, the implication is false. In my opinion, it is pretty clear from the assignment that if the condition $R(x) \lor S(x)$ is satisfied, $P(x)$ will be true, so I don't understand why @Jared said that "it's possible that the passenger does meet those requirements but is not a frequent flyer", I think this definitely shouldn't happen.

However, the intutitive intepretation of such a sentence would be a more generic one (i.e. a rule-like one), meaning that it is not that well suitable to say $x = passenger$, because then, the formula becomes only true if the current variable assignment happens to assign to x an individual which is a passenger, and can therefore also only be true for one individual.
Instead, the sentence should rather say: For everyone who is a passenger it holds that if he passenger flies more than 25,000 miles in one year or takes more than 25 flights during that year, then he is a frequent flier.
Therefore, I would establish another predicate for *passenger*, over which you can then quantify.
Since you already chose $P(x)$ for the *frequent* predicate, let's call $F(x)$ the predicate for *passenger* ("flier").
The formula would then be:
$\forall x [F(x) \to (R(x) \lor S(x) \to P(x))]$
Meaning: For all x ($\forall x$) which are a passenger ($F(x)$) it holds that ($\to$) if he flies more than 25,000 miles in one year ($R(x)$) or ($\lor$) takes more than 25 flights during that year ($S(x)$), then ($\to$) it is a frequent flier ($P(x)$).
This would reflect the semantics of the sentence better IMO, but you can also stick with the more simple variant I gave above.